# C# WinForms | Add Label when Button is Clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, label

Honestly I don't know how to construct my questions. But my idea is, I want to copy the facebook messenger's ui in our case study. We were tasked to make a guessing game.
I don't know how I will code my idea. My plan was to add a new label everytime the send button is clicked, and the panel where the add-on labels will be added will be extended the so that the screen will appear to be sliding.

Here's a screenshot of the winform.

[image]

Here is my Initial Code for the btnSendClicked.

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label lblnew = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        lblnew.Location = new Point(50, 50);
        lblnew.Text = txtMessage.Text;
        lblnew.AutoSize = true;
        lblnew.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
        lblnew.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft JhengHei UI", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        pnlGame.Controls.Add(lblnew);
    }
```

Comment: You need to finish your question with an actual question - we can see what you want to achieve, but what part about it do you need help with?

Comment: I need help in adding new labels. Is my idea possible to be done? I dont know if i should still continue my idea. Its just, i really dont know how to do it hahaha

Comment: You are adding your labels at the same location. I.e. right on top of each other. Try changing the y point value to take in account the height of the previous labels.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the labels you've rendered on the Panel, in order to manage your scrolling mechanism, which could be done by a looping algorithm:

Loop through all `Label` controls in `pnlGame`

- If the current label's Top position is less than or equal to the Top of `pnlGame`, hide the label (Visible = false). The same applies for the Bottom. (remove all labels that should not be visible when scrolling), otherwise, Unhide the label to bring it back into view.

Put the above logic into a method, something like `void RefreshVisiblePanelMessages()`

When clicking on a button to generate a new message, add the new message as a `Label` to your `pnlGame` and then call `RefreshVisiblePanelMessages();` to update the list.